# Python C Extension using numpy and gdal giving undefined symbol at runtime

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, numpy, gdal

I'm writing a C++ extension for python to speed up a raster image viewer created in-house.
I've got working code, but noticed that the speed hadn't increased that much and after profiling a bit deeper realised that it was due to the gdal.ReadAsArray calls, which were python callbacks from the C extension.
To get around the overhead of Python C-API when calling python objects I decided I would use the C++ libraries for gdal rather than using the Python callback to the existing gdalDataset. (space isn't a problem).
However after implementing the code for this I ran into an error at runtime(the extension compiled fine)

which was

```
 import getRasterImage_new
 ImportError: /local1/data/scratch/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    /getRasterImage_new.so: undefined symbol: _ZN11GDALDataset14GetRasterYSizeEv
```

The code below replicates the error(some edits may be needed to run on your machines(ignore the uninitialised variables, it's just whats needed to replicate the error).

Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy
from osgeo import gdal
import PythonCTest

print("test starting")
PythonCTest.testFunction(1)
print("test complete")
```

C++:

```
#include "Python.h"
#include "numpy/arrayobject.h"
#include "gdal_priv.h"
#include <iostream>

extern "C"{
static PyObject* PythonCTest_testFunction(PyObject* args);
static PyMethodDef PythonCTest_newMethods[] = {
   {"testFunction", (PyCFunction)PythonCTest_testFunction, METH_VARARGS,
      "test function"},
   {NULL,NULL,0,NULL}};

PyMODINIT_FUNC initPythonCTest(void){
   (void)Py_InitModule("PythonCTest",PythonCTest_newMethods);
   import_array();
}
}
GDALDataset* y;
static PyObject* PythonCTest_testFunction(PyObject* args){
   std::cout << "in testFunction\n";
   y->GetRasterYSize();
   std::cout << "doing stuff" << "\n";
   return Py_None;
}
```

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

---

EDIT

You can also remove the from osgeo import gdal and the error stull occurs(only just noticed that).

---

EDIT 2

I forgot to say that I'm compiling my extension using distutils

current setup.py is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
import os
os.environ["CC"] = "g++"
setup(name='PythonCTest', version='1.0', \
   ext_modules=[Extension('PythonCTest', ['PythonCTest.cpp'],
   extra_compile_args=['--std=c++14','-l/usr/include/gdal', '-I/usr/include/gdal'])])
```

Comment: When you created your extension, did you have `-lgdal` in the link command?

Comment: I didn't, I had `-Igdal`, have just tried with `-lgdal` with no change

Comment: Add `libraries=['gdal']` to `Extension` constructor invocation to make sure `gdal` is used for linking the module (as opposed to just compilation).

Comment: O wow that worked.. Thank you, can't believe I didn't try that earlier. Had so many problems with this extension. Thanks. If you put that as an answer i'll mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Python extension module is a dynamically loadable (shared) library. When linking a shared library, you need to specify its library dependencies, such as `-lgdal` and, for that matter, `-lpython2.7`. Failing to do so results in a library with unresolved symbols, and if those symbols are not provided by the time it is loaded, the loading will fail, as reported by Python.

To resolve the error, you need to add `libraries=['gdal']` to `Extension` constructor. Specifying `-lgdal` in `extra_compile_args` won't work because compile arguments, as the name implies, are used for compilation and not for linking.

Note that an unresolved symbol would not go undetected when linking an executable, where the build would fail with a linker error. To get the same diagnostics when linking shared libraries, include `-Wl,-zdefs` in link arguments.